# App crash after successfully changed wallpaper

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i'm a beginner in flutter, here i'm trying to make a wallpaper application. my application can run and change the wallpaper, my problem is why does my application crash after success?

```
_saving() async {
    await _askPermissions();
    var response = await Dio().get(
      widget.imgData,
      options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
    );
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        Uint8List.fromList(response.data), name: 'images');
    print(result['filePath']);
    var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(result['filePath']);
    print(path);
    String out;
    try {
      out = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(
          path, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);
    } on PlatformException {
      out = 'Failed to get wallpaper.';
    }
  }
```

i am getting this log

```
D/EGL_emulation(26450): app_time_stats: avg=1550.15ms min=19.34ms max=12037.74ms count=8
I/System.out(26450): ImageGallerySaverPlugin 80
I/flutter (26450): content://media/external/images/media/90
I/flutter (26450): /data/user/0/realfz.flutter.xeed.xeed/cache/IMG_1645634589898.png
E/FA      (26450): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
D/EGL_emulation(26450): eglCreateContext: 0x7d36c51db690: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation(26450): eglCreateContext: 0x7d36c51de750: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/HostConnection(26450): createUnique: call
D/HostConnection(26450): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7d36c51df950, tid 27786
D/HostConnection(26450): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation(26450): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7d36c51de750: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7d38ea0a7200) (first time)
I/Choreographer(26450): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/HostConnection(26450): createUnique: call
D/HostConnection(26450): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7d36c51e36d0, tid 27785
D/HostConnection(26450): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation(26450): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7d36c51db690: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7d38ea0a7100) (first time)
D/EGL_emulation(26450): eglCreateContext: 0x7d36c51e30d0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
I/Choreographer(26450): Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer(26450): Davey! duration=2649ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=113284, IntendedVsync=47817620015088, Vsync=47818436681722, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=47818446770100, AnimationStart=47818446842400, PerformTraversalsStart=47818446945100, DrawStart=47820247194700, FrameDeadline=47817636681754, FrameInterval=47818446237700, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=47820248422100, SyncStart=47820248873100, IssueDrawCommandsStart=47820249153600, SwapBuffers=47820251098700, FrameCompleted=47820270211800, DequeueBufferDuration=10092300, QueueBufferDuration=2055700, GpuCompleted=47820259923000, SwapBuffersCompleted=47820270211800, DisplayPresentTime=8589934592,
```

sorry

Comment: This log does not say much about the error. Can you check the logcat and share that as well?

Comment: in the logs nothing else, but I tried on the smartphone and the app doesn't crash. seems to just crash in emulator. does my emulator have a problem or my code?